# How can I load an image into a tkinter window/canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to have an image show up on a tkinter window. I have managed to do so in the past, but somehow my current attempt is failing at every step. Hopefully someone can guide me to the proper way and help me fix it.

I'm currently trying with this code. The error I'm getting is

_tkinter.TclError: image "paco_img" doesn't exist

```
from tkinter import *



PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
BLUE = "#678ac2"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"


window = Tk()
window.title("Thomas' Elevator Pitch")
window.config(padx=200, pady=100, bg=BLUE)

canvas = Canvas(width=5000, height=4000)

paco_img = PhotoImage(file="paco.png")
canvas.create_image(2500, 2000, image="paco_img")
canvas.pack()
```

I've also tried to do the following, which changes the error to

NameError: name 'ImageTk' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Image'?

However, when I do change ImageTk to Image, it shows PhotoImage as an unresolved attribute reference to Image.

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Thomas' Elevator Pitch")
window.config(padx=200, pady=100, bg=BLUE)

canvas = Canvas(width=5000, height=4000)

paco_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="paco.png")
canvas.create_image(2500, 2000, image="paco_img")
canvas.pack()
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, and suggestions on similar questions asked here didn't work for me yet.

Comment: For the first error `_tkinter.TclError: image "paco_img" doesn't exist`, it's likely because `paco.png` needs to be `the/full/path/to/paco.png` instead. For the second error `NameError: name 'ImageTk' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Image'?`, you'll need to import `ImageTk` in order to use it: `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` - `ImageTk` is part of `PIL`, not `tkinter`

Comment: `image=paco_img` without quotes

Comment: Canvas image objects https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_image.html

Comment: possible without Pillow https://python-course.eu/tkinter/canvas-widgets-in-tkinter.php#:~:text=looks%20like%20this%3A-,The%20Canvas%20Image%20Item,-The%20Canvas%20method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As very well explained in comments by @JRiggles, first you need a Python [library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to handle the image.

Of course, you can install it with [pip](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/):

```
pip install Pillow
```

Then, using the tkinter [hello-world-program](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-hello-world-program) as base, all you need to do is load the necessary libraries, load your image and to display it use either a button or a label widget image param:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



root = Tk()
image = im = Image.open("/path/to/your/image.ext")
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
ttk.Label(frm, image=tk_image).grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```